# Can a gift wrapped item be traded more than once?

Tags: team-fortress-2

On TF2, my friend is trying to transfer a headtaker from an alt account to his main one. I will be moving it. Will I be able to trade it to him, or will I have to unwrap, then rewrap it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the recipient of the gift receives the gift, the option to send the gift will have changed to an unwrap option and so the recipient cannot resend the gift.

So, in short yes. You will have to re-wrap the gift.